# How to draw a dot line between 3d object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a bit of a game where 3d house objects are used.

Also there are some 3d cubes to show the specific points in the house.

I would like to draw dot lines between these 3d cubes so that I can instruct users where to go next kind of things.

I achieved to draw a line in between but not dot lines like the photo attached.

I googled but found nothing...

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I googled 1 second. Lots of people use a dotted texture on repeating on a LineRenderer to achieve this. Check this for example  https://forum.unity.com/threads/dashed-line-in-unity.859204/

Comment: Gosh... Maybe I was searching for wrong terms... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Masa, please close the question, so we know it is solved, :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with help from Kalender.

Go to [the unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/dashed-line-in-unity.859204/) and download the texture unity_31130666 attaches and apply it to LineRenderer with a bit of adjustment of shader.

It all worked.